# Flutter : Flutter_blue bluetooth scan not working properly with Android 4.4.4

Tags: flutter

I am developing my first flutter app .( I am new to mobile app development .)

In my app we need to communicate with ‘custom’ sensor having BLE (4.0) connectivity through mobile app .

While developing mobile app ,one of the major specification is to support for old Android devices i.e. at least KitKat / SDK 19 .

But when I started testing “Fluttter_Blue” with Mi Note 1 LTE , Android 4.4.4 , I am facing issues as follows :

1. “Warning messages when pressed scan button” . In one of your git issues you have mentioned that this will not have any adverse effect but still check if these are the same kind of warning messages or something critical .
2. “Able to scan device but it shows service UUIDs as N/A .During debugging found that ‘result.advertisementData.connectable’ shows 'false' “ .Because of this I am not able to proceed as not able to connect to sensor device

Refer following log :

```
W/dalvikvm( 8325): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanResult;)
I/dalvikvm( 8325): Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult.getScanRecord, referenced from method com.pauldemarco.flutterblue.ProtoMaker.from
W/dalvikvm( 8325): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 322:Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanResult;.getScanRecord ()Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord;
D/dalvikvm( 8325): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f**
```

Please refer attached :Terminal Log ,app-src-build.gradle,geadle-build.gradle,pubspec.yaml

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14MKC2x8imM9gHtV5zxgdvCtOxXdz-C62?usp=sharing